# How to convert a class object to generic object type?

Tags: java, mysql, object, generics, jdbc

I'm working on a method to get some data from MySQL database using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. The `listCurrentRecords` should return List of Objects types of either `Customer`, `Product` and `SalesOrder` from database. The `objectType` is defined from the parameter passed inside the method (1 || 2 || 3) and it is defined earlier in the class as public variable.

```
public static final int TYPE_PRODUCT = 1;
public static final int TYPE_CUSTOMER = 2;
public static final int TYPE_SALESORDER = 3;
```

The method is provided below.

```
public static List<Object> listCurrentRecords(int objectType)
{

    // PRODUCT 
    if ( objectType == 1 ){

    }

    //CUSTOMER 
    else if ( objectType ==  2 ){

    }

    // SALESORDER
    else if ( objectType ==  3 ){

    }

    return null; 
    // return new ArrayList<Object>();
}
```

Say, the `objectType == 2`, then it will require to grab some data from the `Customer` table using `getMyCustomer` method ( same goes for the `Product` and `SalesOrder`, they will use their separate methods ) as following,

```
public static List<Customer> getMyCustomer(){

    return jdbc.query("select * from Customer", new RowMapper<Customer>() {

        public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            Customer customer = new Customer();

            customer.setCustomerID(rs.getString("CustomerID"));
            customer.setName( rs.getString("Name"));
            customer.setAddress( rs.getNString("Address"));
            customer.setPhone1(rs.getNString("Phone 1"));
            customer.setPhone2(rs.getNString("Phone 2"));

            customer.setCreditLimit(rs.getDouble("Credit Limit"));
            customer.setCurrentCredit(rs.getDouble("Current Credit"));

            return customer;
        }
    });
```

Inside the `else if ( objectType ==  2 ){  }` I would like to call `getMyCustomer` method and get `List<Customer>` there. However, the return type of the method `listCurrentRecords` is `List<Object>`. How to convert from `List<Customer>` to `List<Object>`. I provided the pseudo code as following,

```
   // customer 
    else if ( objectType ==  2 ){

         List<Customer> myCustomer =  getMyCustomer();
         // how to convert ***myCustomer*** to List<Object> ?
    }
```

I appreciate some assistance of how to write it properly in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the `Object` type (remember generics are a compile time type checking feature), you can use `addAll` or the constructor that takes a second `List`. Like

```
List<Object> myCustomer = new ArrayList<>(getMyCustomer());
```

**or**

```
List<Object> al = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
al.addAll(getMyCustomer());
```

Comment: For me the last solution works. I'm still working on the project, I will provide the more feedback later on.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do

```
List<Object> myCustomer = new ArrayList<>(getMyCustomer());
```

This creates a new list by iterating over the original, so could be slow depending on the size of the list.

If this is a problem, an alternative is to do

```
List<Object> myCustomer = Collections.unmodifiableList(getMyCustomer());
```

This version works by wrapping the original list. If you do it this way you will not be able to call any methods that modify the list (`add`, `set`, `remove`, `clear` etc).

Comment: I don't know the reason, both of the solutions doesn't work for me. I used the earlier answer as following,
List<Object> al = new ArrayList<>();

al.addAll(getMyCustomer());

Comment: Oh OK. Sorry my answer didn't help. I'm glad you found your answer.

Comment: Never mind, I'm still learning how to write a complete application in Java. Actually, the previous answer also provided your first answer. I'm using Java 1.7 it may be an issue with the version ?

Comment: Both my answers should work on Java 1.7. Actually the second should work on Java 1.5 as it doesn't use the diamond <>.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative approach you may consider apart from other answers which construct a new `List<Object>` base on your `List<Customer>`

Your `listCurrentRecords(int objectType)` is under your control anyway, if there are no reason of really need to return `List<Object>`, you may simply change it to `public static List<?> listCurrentRecords(int objectType)`.

Actually it is not a very good idea to use wildcard in return type.  Let's take one step further, why don't make `listCurrentRecords` return the proper list instead? For example, instead of passing in an integer, pass in the `Class` of the type of data you want, e.g.

```
public static <T> List<T> listCurrentRecords(Class<T> dataType)
```

so the caller can receive a proper list of, for example, `Customer` by

```
List<Customer> = listCurrentRecords(Customer.class)
```

Comment: something a bit off-topic... do you really want to keep using such design?  It just doesn't look right. A super method that give you "current records" of different irrelevant entities?....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The methods are defined in the app I'm working on, but, I will test your solutions soon.